# Two webdrivers to access a same website so that username password is used in only one driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need two different webDrivers for two different tabs in same window so that only once login will be done, Is that possible? {python}

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver2.get(page_url_c)
time.sleep(5)
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
for cookie in cookies:
    driver2.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Comment: Why do you need to use 2 webdriver if you can do it with a single webdriver?

Comment: Cookies are a good starting point. For some websites, you might also need to copy the __local storage__ tho.